# CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn and Web Deploy

Tags: deployment, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I am using Web Deploy feature of Visual Studio 2015 to deploy my Type Script SPA project to my staging server.

I want the deployment process to copy (and rename) some deployment specific files from /Deployment folder of my project to other specific locations of the project.

One such example is:

[project_root]/Deployment/index.remote.debug.html ---> [project_root]/index.html

I managed to achieve this using the following section in my publish profile (.pubxml):

```xml
<Target Name="index_html">
  <ItemGroup>
    <_CustomFiles Include="Deployment/index.remote.debug.html" />
    <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
      <DestinationRelativePath>index.html</DestinationRelativePath>
    </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
<Target Name="extractor_config">
  <ItemGroup>
    <_CustomFiles Include="Deployment/extractor.config.remote.debug.js" />
    <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
      <DestinationRelativePath>extractor.config.js</DestinationRelativePath>
    </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<PropertyGroup>
  <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
    index_html;
    $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
  </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
  <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
    extractor_config;
    $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
  </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>

</PropertyGroup>
```

But this works only when publishing to file system with 'File System' option.
When publishing to my staging server using 'Web Deploy' option, I see no effect.
The application is correctly deployed but respective files don't get copied/renamed.

There is also no error message in Visual Studio output related to such a web deploy.

It makes no difference if I deploy as non-admin or admin.

Does anybody know, where is the problem?

With respect to MSBuild I am a total layman and this is my first encounter. I've put this together only with help of other people's online experience.

Comment: This is the article I used to set up my .pubxml: http://www.baconapplications.com/custom-publish-with-visual-studio-2013/

Comment: I added Message element to both Targets to see if the target gets executed. Obviously, the message appears on local deployment but not on web deployment.

Comment: Just for your amusement - my frustration went as far as to make me hastily create a server based windows service called 'post-deployment steps', which detects new deployment and makes all necessary additional steps. I'm just asking, is this not telling something important about MSBuilds usability and comprehensibility? The fact that a person capable of creating service based solution in 30 min can't figure out MSBuild way in whole weekend? Just server based copying of files after deployment. No rocket science.

Comment: Somewhat shameless plug, but did either of the answers help?

Answer (score 12):

You need an element with a slightly different name. You have:

```
  <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
    index_html;
    $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
  </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
  <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
    extractor_config;
    $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
  </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
```

Try having a nearly identical section but with this tag:

```
  <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
```

Notice it is ForMsdeploy not ForPackage

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Rhyous's excellent answer, note that the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-extra-files) indicate you should have both `CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn` and `CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn`, e.g.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>

    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I have gotten this to work by editing the project file, but the referenced doc has this edit made in the publish profile file, which I suppose is more efficient.